# Mesh for points in 3D

Tags: mesh

I've got a set of Eisenstein integers (triangle lattice points in the complex plane), and I've selected them to be above a line, so that they form a triangle:

[image: eisenstein triangle above line]

I then took these 2D points and embedded them in 3D space, with the z-axis chosen randomly:

```
points3d = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], RandomReal[]} &, eisensteinIntegers]
Graphics3D[Point /@ points3d, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: 3d points]

I would like to have those points form a triangular mesh, similiar to the Delaunay mesh for the eisenstein integers:

[image: Delaunay mesh]

Except that the Delaunay mesh on the 3D points forms a solid, not a surface. How can I form a mesh surface from these points?

Comment: It helps posting working code. Retyping code and thinking about how to get `einsteinIntegers` takes to long for me to consider answering. Use `MeshCoordinates` and `Join` a 3rd coordinate and then with `MeshCells` extract the faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is morally like ListPlot3D[], but that does the wrong thing. To do the right thing, do the following:

```
instantiatePoly[p_, ptlist_] := Map[ptlist[[#]] &, p]

drawFunc[planar_, vals_] := 
  Module[{triples = MapThread[Append, {planar, vals}]},
  Graphics3D[
     Map[instantiatePoly[#, triples] &, 
                     MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[planar], 2]]]]
```

Now, if `planar` is your set of points in the plane, and `vals` is the list of values at those points (should obviously be the same length), you will get what you want, like so (for a different subset  of Eisenstein integers). Of course, you can customize this up the wazoo if you are so inclined.

[image]